Powershell The term HandleException is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
I have a PowerShell script where it will have to fetch the workspace details and run "ForEach" method.
while running the script I'm getting the below error that says.
"HandleException : The term 'HandleException' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
Sample PowerShell script used:
Write-Output "Connecting Azure through xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx SPN login"
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb -ApplicationId $appId

#Get all workspaces from given tenant
$workspace = GetWorkspaceDetails  -UCApiBaseUrl $UCApiBaseUrl 
Write-Output "Total workspaces found"
$workspace.Count
$workspace
$edpWorkspaces = $workspace |Where-Object { $_.workspace_name -Like "az-dna-*" }
Write-Output "EDP filtered workspaces are "
$edpWorkspaces.Count
    try
    {
    $edpWorkspaces|ForEach-Object{
    $workspace_item = $_
    $workspace_item
    #Get External Locations
       $externalLocations= GetExternalLocations -WorkspaceDeploymentName $($workspace.deployment_name)
       $externalLocations
}
    }
catch {    
    $ErrorMsg = HandleException -ErrorBody $_
    Write-Error $ErrorMsg
    exit 1
 }


There is no inbuilt Function called HandleException.

I believe the try method is not getting executed. Can you elaborate or paste a sample inbuilt function to my code/

Posted an answer below with that @Nolan1513


Powershell The term HandleException is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

There is no inbuilt function called as HandleException, but you can create user-defined HandleException function as below:
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
function HandleException {
    param(
        [string]$ritherror
    )
        Write-Host "Hello Rithwik Error has been occurred: $ritherror"
}
try {
    $out = Get-Item -Path "NoFile.txt"
}
catch {
    HandleException -ritherror $_.Exception.Message
}

You should use $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" then only catch works when you have a command and it gives output/error.
Output:

